# Find Unique Data List from array object amenities Like result

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
**Filter unique object from amenities list like result using JavaScript**
```

amenities = [
{
"name": "Pool"
},
{
"name": "Laundry"
},
{
"name": "Wifi"
},
{
"name": "BBQ Grill"
},
{
"name": "Barth top"
},
{
"name": "Pool"
},
{
"name": "Laundry"
},
{
"name": "Wifi"
},
{
"name": "BBQ Grill"
},
{
"name": "Barth top"
},
{
"name": "Pool"
},
{
"name": "Laundry"
},
{
"name": "Wifi"
},
{
"name": "BBQ Grill"
},
{
"name": "Barth top"
}
]

```
result = [ 
{
            "name": "Pool"
        },
        {
            "name": "Laundry"
        },
        {
            "name": "Wifi"
        },
        {
            "name": "BBQ Grill"
        },
        {
            "name": "Barth top"
        }]
```

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

You cand do:

```js
const amenities = [ { "name": "Pool" }, { "name": "Laundry" }, { "name": "Wifi" }, { "name": "BBQ Grill" }, { "name": "Barth top" }, { "name": "Pool" }, { "name": "Laundry" }, { "name": "Wifi" }, { "name": "BBQ Grill" }, { "name": "Barth top" }, { "name": "Pool" }, { "name": "Laundry" }, { "name": "Wifi" }, { "name": "BBQ Grill" }, { "name": "Barth top" } ]
const amenitiesHash = amenities.reduce((a, c) => (a[c.name] = c, a), {})
const result = Object.values(amenitiesHash)

console.log(result)
```